# jQuery: Display submit button next to selected checkbox when <li> is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, label

I have a time slot listed in an unordered list (ul li) with a checkbox in it too. When the user clicks on the checkbox, submit button appears next to the time slot. I have managed to execute the first step here.

The next thing I have to do is displaying the submit button when user clicks on any part of the time slot (not necessarily the checkbox) which I have not succeeded to do

To illustrate this, I have setup a **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/hz2t4/46/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put **checkbox** and **text** between the `label` tag

```
<ul class="timeSlot clearfix">
    <li><label>12:00am - 01:00am <input type="checkbox"></label><input type="submit" value="Continue to Step 2"  style="display:none;"></li>
    <li><label>01:00am - 02:00am <input type="checkbox"></label></li>
</ul>​
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/hz2t4/49/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your checkbox inputs in a label and it will do what you want it to:

```
<label><input type="checkbox"></label>
```

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz2t4/48/) to demonstrate.